# uWSGI: Spawning a long-lived process

Tags: python, uwsgi

I would like to run some code in a uWSGI app, but on a long-lived process, not inside workers. That's because the process blocks on a socket `recv()` call, and only one thread of execution should do this.

I am hoping to avoiding creating my own daemon by somehow starting a long-lived process on uWSGI startup that does not get spawned in each worker.

Does uWSGI support anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uWSGI Mules are like workers but without network access:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Mules.html